# How can I prevent stacked inline-block divs from "breaking" on mobile?

Tags: css, mobile, responsive-design, responsive

Ran into a really weird problem and hopefully somebody can help...

I have a few rows of inline-block elements stacked on top of each other, so that they all merge into one guitar fretboard. On web/desktop, there is no visible line break (they are merged well). However on mobile, you can see a line break, until you zoom in all the way. Here are some pictures:

[image]
This first pictures shows the line breaks. I don't want these.

[image]
This second picture shows the line breaks disappearing when I zoom in further. This is what I would like.

Does anybody know why this happens? How can I fix it? I would prefer not to have to recode everything and step away from this inline-block element approach, but if I have to I will. I figured out a temporary work around which is to stick a background-color of brown behind the entire fretboard div, but the light line breaks will show up for anything that's not brown.

Comment: You can set `min-wdith` in their parents..!

Comment: Can you explain how adding a min-width will help? From my understanding, the width always stays constant regardless of the zooming on mobile.

Comment: If you will add `min-width` in their parent, in mobile view the parent will not shrink and the children will get the enough space to stay horizontal..! But you will need to scroll the content on mobile horizontally.

Comment: Your HTML/CSS code please

Comment: a Fiddle of [self-contained sample of code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would really help